# OnBlur cancel's my save event

Tags: javascript

I validate a string length (4000 bytes) and if it's longer, I trim it, return a message "Text too long and was trimmed."

I want the original even to fire anyway (a submit button).

Would window.alert() cancel the form submit?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: cancels <-- no apostrophe, it's not possessive form, as in "Mike's house"

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't.

Consider this code:

```
$('body').on('click', function() {
    window.alert('clicked');
    console.log('keeps executing after the alert is dismissed');
});
```

The alert pauses execution of the next line of code. But when it's dismissed execution continues. So if this was a submit event the submit would still go through.

If you want to cancel the submit, you can use:

```
return false;
```